# Android SQL data not adding to DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to write an Android app to let me add data to a DB and then View it. I have been following a YouTube tutorial. When I click the "add Data" button, I get the Toast message that tells me the data was added. But when I click The View All button, it tells me that there is no data. I used File explorer to check the DB file and there is nothing saved in there. I'm not very familiar with using SQL with an Android app, but I'm trying to learn.

Here is the DBHelper Class

```
package com.example.fourth;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Bars.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Bar_info";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String BAR_NAAME = "Bar Name";
    public static final String BAR_CITY = "Bar City";
    public static final String DRINK_NAME = "Drink Name";
    //public static final String DRINK_PRICE = "Drink Price";
    //public static final String DRINK_TYPE = "Drink Type";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, BAR_NAME TEXT, "
                + "BAR_CITY TEXT, DRINK_NAME TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    public boolean insertData(String bar_name, String bar_city, String drink_name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(BAR_NAAME,bar_name);
        contentValues.put(BAR_CITY ,bar_city);
        contentValues.put(DRINK_NAME,drink_name);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
        }
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res  = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }

    }
```

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fourth;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    DBHelper myDB;
    EditText editBarName, editBarCity, editDrinkName;
    Button btnAddData, btnViewAll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB = new DBHelper(this);

        editBarName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBarName);
        editBarCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBarCity);
        editDrinkName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDrinkName);
        btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddData);
        btnViewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewAll);
        AddData();
        ViewAll();
    }

    public void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isInsterted = myDB.insertData(editBarName.getText().toString(),
                        editBarCity.getText().toString(), editDrinkName.getText().toString());
                if (isInsterted = true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void ViewAll() {
        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor res = myDB.getAllData();
                if(res.getCount() ==0){
                    // show message 
                    showMessage("Error", "No Data Found");
                    return;
                }

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()){
                    buffer.append("ID :"+ res.getString(0)+ "\n");
                    buffer.append("Bar Name :"+ res.getString(1)+ "\n");
                    buffer.append("Bar City :"+ res.getString(2)+ "\n");
                    buffer.append("Drink Name :"+ res.getString(3)+ "\n\n");

                }
                //Show All Data
                showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void showMessage(String title, String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity.xml page

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fourth.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Bar Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Bar City"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Drink Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editBarName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editBarCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDrinkName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editBarCity"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Add Data" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:text="View All" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what it displays when you click on `View` button

Comment: "Error No Data Found". The error message that is supposed to pop up when there is no data. But there SHOULD be data, since I filled in the text fields and clicked "Add Data", which gave me the Toast letting me know it was added

Comment: is there any error or exception in logcat??

Comment: add `db.close();` after `db.insert()` function in `insertData` function of `DBHelper` class

Comment: 03-12 00:23:08.440: E/SQLiteDatabase(6241): Error inserting Bar Name=sfdsaf Bar City=asdfasdf Drink Name=asdfasdf

03-12 00:23:08.440: E/SQLiteDatabase(6241): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Bar_info(Bar Name,Bar City,Drink Name) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: read the answer below..it'll solve your problem..You should know the naming conventions of database..

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning and will hopefully be better soon. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create the table

```
Public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ Bar_Name + "TEXT ,"
                + Bar_city+ "TEXT," + Drink_Name + "TEXT");
```

change name

```
public static final String BAR_NAAME = "Bar_Name";
public static final String BAR_CITY = "Bar_City";
public static final String DRINK_NAME = "Drink_Name";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You're **assigning** the `isInserted` value to true. You should **compare** the value with == and not a single =.

**Replace**  if (isInsterted = true) **With** `if (isInsterted == true)`.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed that.

Answer (score -1):

create a table like this...............Hope its help u

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


          System.out.println("table...........................................................");

          String myTABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +quizTABLE+ "(" 
                    + KEY_QNO + " TEXT," + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_OPTION1 + " TEXT," + KEY_OPTION2 + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_OPTION3 + " TEXT," + KEY_OPTION4 + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT" + ")";


          db.execSQL(myTABLE);

          Log.d("Table create.........................","TABLE CREATE SUCCESSFULYL");

    }
```

Comment: What is the benefit to creating the table this way vs the changes suggested above to the creation method I had?